# return loop results for another method

Tags: java, string

Its a loan calculator. I have a loop like

```
    public String loopresult(){
     for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
     return ((i) + "..........." + (i)*(i))
     }
```

It says this class must return String value. 
I tried

```
    valueOf.String((i) + "........" +(i)*(i)))
```

but didnt work.

I have to append it in txtArea.

```
    txtArea.append(loopresult())
```

what i want inside txtArea is like

2.........4
3.........9
so on, so it means this line will have int and string both.

Comment: what actually you want to append to txtarea? 1....1, 2....4 etc.,?

Comment: Can you post the stack-trace?

Comment: I want to append as 2..........4, 3...........9 like on

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu Can you explain how that would help?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely what you intended was the following.  You can only return one value, not multiple values.  BTW You have a String already so your error message is confused.

```
 public String loopresult(){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
         sb.append(i + "..........." + i*i + "\n");
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: The error message was correct, the compiler just wanted a return statement after the `for` loop too.

Comment: Apologies for my first comment, better get a cup of coffee myself :-) But i wonder since when an expression of type "int + String" is valid in Java, i suppose in previous versions we had to say `"" + i + "......"` ?

Comment: @GyroGearless I don't believe you ever needed to write `"" + i + "string"`  You can write it that way for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

return value will only return once, you have to append and return after the for loop, try the below code

```
public String loopresult() {
        String finalValue = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            finalValue += (i) + "..........." + (i) * (i);
        }
        return finalValue;
    }
```

Comment: Most likely you want a separator between the lines. ;)

Comment: Also, use a `StringBuilder` while building the result.

Comment: Never use s `String` to accumulate something!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, for cleaner and easier to read code would be, to have the function return the int value of each separate loan, and then construct the string outside that logic.
If I understand your question correctly.

Give us more details. What do you want to write to the text area? Several different loan values?

Answer (score -1):

Compiler is giving warning because you are using **for** loop. It might happen that condition(for some dynamic value) in for loop fails for the first time itself and flow will not go in the for loop and that's why compiler is forcing you to write a return statement after for loop.

Also as @Peter Lawrey said, you cannot return multiple values from a function. So you can use the given by Peter Lawrey

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
         sb.append(i + "..........." + i*i + "\n");
     return sb.toString();
```

or you can replace your for loop with **do..while** where flow will go in the loop for sure, although I don't think that's a solution but I am giving this to show why compiler is forcing return statement after for loop.

```
int i = 1;
do{
    return ((i) + "..........." + (i) * (i));
    ++i;
}while(i<10);
```

Comment: But will return on first iteration! Which is basically a good thing, because it would be an infinite loop otherwise.

Comment: @GyroGearless do while loop is only to show why compiler is forcing return statement after for loop and not essentially the solution.