# Why method is not returning null, If method contains another return in loop

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test test = new Test();
    String str = test.methodTest();
    System.out.println("Output : "+str);
}

public String methodTest(){

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i==5){
            return new String("We got 5 :)");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Expected output for String str=null
Output : str = We got 5 :)

Can anybody explain me why it's happening?

Comment: `5` is lesser than `10`, so it is natural that the string is returned. Why returning `null` is expected?

Comment: No, `return` is return from the function, not only the loop.

Comment: What makes you think that `return` *would* just exit the loop, not the whole method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return loop results for another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852674/return-loop-results-for-another-method)

Comment: U can have any number of return statements inside your method. But whenever the first return statement is executed the control will be moved from the current method and it will not execute any of the code followed by the current return statement

Comment: Debugging in IntelliJ IDEA confused me. It went to return null; statement aswell, this confuse me and make me post this question :)

Answer (score 1):

`i` will take on the values 0-9 for the duration of your `for` loop. However, then `i==5`, the code enclosed in the `if` statement will execute. This `return`s a String of `"We got 5 :)"` and **terminates the method**. Thus, the second `return` statement is never reached. Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html),

> A method returns to the code that invoked it when it [...] reaches a `return` statement

Reiterating, control flow is relinquished back to the caller (in this case the `main` method) at the appearance of the first `return` statement reached, which in this case is inside of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are confused with `return` and `break` statement. a `return` will end the method and will return to the caller statement. But if you want to end a loop then you need `break`. For the expected output(str == null) on your same code, you can do just use `break`

```
public String methodTest(){

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i==5){
            break;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is incrementing i by 1, starting at 0, each iteration. Once i is equal to 5 (hence your code `i==5`) the `if` statement becomes true and then the code within is executed. The `return` statement is then executed, which exits the whole method and "returns" to the calling method, in this case the main method. No other code after that `return` statement is executed, including the second `return` statement to return the null value.

If you want the second `return` statement to be reached, then you can create a global variable, or provide a parameter for `methodTest` to manipulate.

Answer (score -1):

Since only one `return` statement can execute for any `method` . Once you return from the `method` , then program return that value and execution stops or terminates .   You can only `return` **1** value . If you want to return *2* or more values you can put values in object and then `return`  `obj` .

Answer (score -1):

It is returning "We got 5" as it iterates through 1 to 10 and number 5 is with in that range you will return the string instead of null.